# create a table in td using zend decorator

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-decorators

I am using zend forms and zend decorators.

I want to create a sub-table in a parent table's td. like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
   <td>Username:</td>
   <td>
     <table>
      <tr>
       <td> <input type="text"> </td>
       <td> <img/> </td>
      </tr>
     </table>
   </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

How can i create this table.
can anyone help me plz.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the best solution, as you maybe able to create your own decorator to render the form (with the sub-tables). But you could always render each form element individually, using the *renderViewHelper()* function

```
<table>
  <tr>
   <td>Username:</td>
   <td>
     <table>
      <tr>
       <td><?php echo $this->form->username->renderViewHelper() ?></td>
       <td> <img/> </td>
      </tr>
     </table>
   </td>
  </tr>  <tr>
   <td>AnotherElement:</td>
   <td>
     <table>
      <tr>
       <td><?php echo $this->form->anotherElement->renderViewHelper() ?></td>
       <td> <img/> </td>
      </tr>
     </table>
   </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```